# I can't remove white spaces from nokogiri node content

Tags: ruby, string, nokogiri

Code:

```
digits.each do |digit|
  puts digit.content #&0000000000032056.00000032 056
  value = digit.content[24..-1].strip
  puts value #32 056 it's ok
  puts value.gsub(/\s+/, "") #32 056 !!!! I expected 32056
  population << value
end
```

I don't understand why gsub does not work as I expected :/ Could somebody help?

**[EDIT]**

Anyway I do it another way:

```
  value = digit.content.split(".")[0]
  value = value[12..-1].strip
```

but I am still wonder, why first solution sucks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to try:

If you're checking the `population` variable, your method doesn't actually put the substitution in it. Change the last line to:

```
population << value.gsub(/\s+/, "")
```

If that still doesn't work, perhaps there is some non-space character that looks like a space in your terminal? Try replacing non-digits instead:

```
population << value.gsub(/\D/, "")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
digit='&0000000000032056.00000032 056'
value = digit[24..-1].strip
puts value #32 056
puts value.gsub(/\s+/, "") #32056
```

Is your value string?

Comment: puts value.class gives me String :/, puts digit.content.class is String too. Maybe wikipedia has some kind of parsing protection? I try to parse: http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miasta_w_Polsce_(statystyki) (5th column values)

Comment: Ooops I totally forget about &nbsp; Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

just take what you need!

```
value.gsub(/[^0-9]+/, '')
```